# Help with an identity involving PolyLog and Logs.

Tags: logarithms, special-functions

I am plotting the following expression on Mathematica 
$$ 
\Im\left[-96 \text{Li}_3\left(e^{-i
   t}\right)-48 t^2 \log
   \left(1-e^{-i t}\right)\right]-96
   \Re\left[t \text{Li}_2\left(e^{-i
   t}\right)\right]-8
   t^3)
$$ 
over a range of $t \in (0,2\pi)$, and find it to be of the order of $10^{-17}$, and very noisy. Often this happens because the actual value is zero, so I was wondering if such a thing can be shown using some identities involving Clausen functions ? I tried looking at few identities in wiki and wolfram but was not of much help.

Comment: How did you arrive at this expression? Some context could be helpful for understanding this behavior.

Comment: it comes in the context of doing a definite integral over a square region, $x \ in (0,t), y \in (0,t)$ of the integrand $(1 - \frac{(x-y)}{2} \cot(\frac{x-y}{2}))^2 (1 - \frac{2\pi - x}{2} \cot (\frac{x-y}{2}))$